# On the basis of the Free Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a set and $C(X)$ the set of all functions $f: X \to \mathbb{K}$ (here $\mathbb{K}$ is some field) with only finitely many $f(x) \neq 0$. For each $a \in X$, let us define:
$$f_{a}(x) := \begin{cases} \displaystyle 1 \quad \mbox{if $x=a$} \\ \displaystyle 0 \quad \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
Then it is not difficult to prove that the collection of such $\{f_{a}\}_{a\in X}$ is a basis for $C(X)$. The space $C(X)$ is known as the free vector space generated by $X$.

Now, take $X = U\times V$ where $U,V$ are both vector spaces over $\mathbb{K}$. If $f \in C(U\times V)$, by the above discussion we can write $f$ as a sum:
\begin{eqnarray}
f(u,v) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\alpha_{i}f_{(u_{i},v_{i})}(u,v) \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
where (for all $i=1,...,N$) $\alpha_{i} \in \mathbb{K}$, $u_{i}\in U$ and $v_{i}\in V$. However, some authors usually write:
\begin{eqnarray}
f(u,v) = \sum_{i,j}\alpha_{ij}f_{(u_{i},v_{j})}(u,v) \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{eqnarray}
instead of (\ref{1}), where, now, $i$ and $j$ range over different finite sets. I know that if you set $\alpha_{ij} = \delta_{ij}\alpha_{i}$ the second expression for $f$ becomes the first one but isn't it a little bit artificial? I mean, isn't (\ref{1}) the most natural way to write $f \in C(U\times V)$? Why adopt (\ref{2}) as a representation?

Comment: One "unnatural" aspect of your preferred representation is that we might be forced to have $u_i = u_j$ with $i \neq j$

Comment: But isn't the whole point of saying that $\{f_{a}\}_{a\in X}$ is a basis for $C(X)$? I mean, do I need something else?

Comment: Well it is convenient to have the $u_i$ uniquely indexed if you're going to do something with the underlying spaces $U,V$ from which $X$ is formed. Ultimately, the point of bringing attention to the fact that $X = U \times V$ is presumably that the author is going to do something within the set of functions that "takes advantage" of $X$'s extra structure

Comment: In particular, if we want to relate $C(X)$ to $C(U)$ and $C(V)$, then this doubly-indexed summation is often convenient. For instance, it is handy if we want to describe an isomorphism between $C(X)$ and $C(U) \otimes C(V)$